# How to pass parameters through link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Rails ver. 5.0.0.1

I want to create and assign a new property via link_to from a portfolio SHOW page. The link should pass portfolio_id as a parameter and save after completing the remaining property form.

I've seen this questions asked multiple times, but for some reason applying the correct answer in my own app isn't working. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
# portfolio show.html.erb

<%= link_to 'Add New Property To This Portfolio', new_property_path(:portfolio_id => @portfolio.id) %>

# properties controller

def new
@portfolio = :portfolio
@property = Property.new(params[:portfolio_id => @portfolio])
end

# portfolio model

has_many :properties

# property model

belongs_to :portfolio
accepts_nested_attributes_for :portfolio
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the params just fine, but you're not reading them correctly. Your current code:

```
def new
  @portfolio = :portfolio
  @property = Property.new(params[:portfolio_id => @portfolio])
end
```

should read:

```
def new

  # Rails stores params passed through a link_to in the params
  # hash, like any other parameter

  @portfolio = params[:portfolio]
  @property = Property.new(params[:portfolio_id => @portfolio])
end
```

There are some other issues with your code that you might want to address:

1) You have a field called `@portfolio`, but it contains an id. Normally, a plain name like that would store an instance of a `Portfolio` object. When a field stores an `id`, append `_id` to the end. It helps people understand what's in the field, and gives a good guess as to the datatype (important for scripting languages like Ruby);

2) Are you sure you want your `link_to` to go to the `new` method? What happens when someone uses the another path to get to `new` (like entering the URL in the browser), without setting a `portfolio_id`? Won't your code break?

3) Are you sure you can create a `Property` object with just a `portfolio_id`? Normally, you'd pass `property_params` to the new method to create a new `Property`.

These things are all things you should address in different questions once you think about them for a while, but passing params via `link_to` should be resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to accept `nested_attributes` of `property` model within `portfolio` model. Then, from show page of portfolio , you can add `property` for a particular `portfolio` using `link_to_add` method.

***Portfolio model***

```
has_many :properties
accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties, :allow_destroy => true,, reject_if: :all_blank
```

**Property model**

```
belongs_to :portfolio
```

***PortfoliosController.rb***

```
##Build in new method:

def new
  @portfolio_object = Portfolio.new
  @portfolio_object.properties.build
end
```

Accept nested attributes in private method

```
private

def portfolio_params      
  params.require(:portfolio).permit(:list_of_portfolio_parameters, properties_attributes: [ :list_of_properties_parameters, :_destroy ])
end
```

Then build `property` attributes in your `Portfolio` `new` method's html page. Hope it will help you.